# Validating textarea field on WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, validation, security

I have a textarea that I want to validate:

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea"></textarea>
</form>
```

Sending the value using Ajax:

```
$.ajax('ajaxurl', {
    method: "POST",
    data: {'action': 'my_action', 'textarea': $('#textarea').val()},
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
});
```

In `functions.php`:

```
function my_action(){
    $textarea = $_POST['textarea'];
    if ( !empty( $textarea ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $textarea = sanitize_textarea_field($textarea);
        $wpdb->insert( 'data_table', array('textarea' => $textarea), array('%s') );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
```

Is the `sanitize_textarea_field()` enough to validate the textarea? Or I have make some more checks?

Answer (score 0):

```
sanitize_textarea_field()
```

will do the following

- Checks for invalid UTF-8
- Converts single < characters to entities
- Strips all tags
- Removes line breaks, tabs, and extra whitespace
- Strips octets

Though from the data perspective this should be enough , however i will suggest that from the security perspective you should limit the size of input as well

Comment: What about SQL injection in this case?

Comment: Well the text area is not only the only surface vulnerable to SQL injection there are other points too.. this gives you a much broader insight into securing the WordPress site.. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/wordpress-sql-injection-tools-techniques/